# In xsd how to redeclare different group elements under choice

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following two elements , product and customerAccount.

The product has the following structure, with two elements , productSerialNumber and serviceGuidingIdentifer

```
<xs:element name="product">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="productSerialNumber" type="xs:string" />
     <xs:element name="serviceGuidingIdentifer">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
             <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 
  </xs:sequence>                                                                     
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The customer Account has the following structure

```
<xs:element name="customerAccount">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID"type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Now i would like to have a choice where the user can declare only one of the three elements above , that is any one of 
1)productSerialNumber
OR 
2)serviceGuidingIdentifer
OR
3)customerAccount

whenever i am trying to declare the choice , i face the error saying either element not found or element definition inconsistent .

I have tried the following choice declaration

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="tns:productSerialNumber"/>
    <xs:element ref="tns:serviceGuidingIdentifer"/>
    <xs:element ref="tns:customerAccount"/>
</xs:choice>
```

What is the right way of re declaring different group elements in a choice .

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks and Regards,
Dev

Answer (score 1):

At least two of your elements are not top-level, so you can not "ref" them. The following schema is valid (in Eclipse):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:productSerialNumber" />
                <xs:element ref="tns:serviceGuidingIdentifer" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="productSerialNumber" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="serviceGuidingIdentifer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="customerAccount">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="choice-element">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="tns:productSerialNumber" />
                <xs:element ref="tns:serviceGuidingIdentifer" />
                <xs:element ref="tns:customerAccount" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</schema>
```

Comment: Its important to note that **any** top level element can be validly used as a root element in a document based on that schema, which may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for that quick reply .  The sad part being is that i am using soapUI which is throwing an error during load time saying "element not found" for all references made in <xs:element ref> . I think while parsing it is not considering the namespace .   We will be using soapUI so i am not too sure what can make the UI parse this correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you define them as complex types you can as type of ref instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.Product" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.Product" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="product">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element name="productSerialNumber" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="serviceGuidingIndetifier" type="serviceGuidingIdentiferType" />
                <xs:element name="customerAccount" type="customerAccountType" />
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="serviceGuidingIdentiferType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="customerAccountType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```